# Should I actively be deleting old docker images to clear disk space?

Tags: docker

I use docker to build a web app (a Rails app specifically).

Each build is tagged with the git SHA value and the `:latest` tag points to the latest SHA value (e.g. `4bfcf8d`) in this case.

```
# docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              SIZE
feeder_web          4bfcf8d             c2f766746901        About a minute ago   1.61GB
feeder_web          latest              c2f766746901        About a minute ago   1.61GB
feeder_web          c14c3e6             4cb983fbf407        13 minutes ago       1.61GB
feeder_web          cc1ecd9             3923b2c0c77f        18 minutes ago       1.61GB
```

Each version only differs by some minor copy in the app's frontend, but other than that they are largely the same.

Each one is listed at 1.61GB. Does it really require an additional 1.61GB for each build if I just change a few lines in the web app? And if so, should I actively be clearing old builds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Each version only differs by some minor copy in the app's frontend, but other than that they are largely the same. Each one is listed at 1.61GB. Does it really require an additional 1.61GB for each build if I just change a few lines in the web app?

Whether or not you can benefit from layer caching depends largely on how you write your Dockerfile.

For example if you write

```
FROM debian
COPY ./code /code
RUN apt-get update && all that jazz ... ... 
...
```

and you change one iota of that `./code`, the whole layer is tossed and every layer after it.  Docker has to rerun (and re-*store*) your layer, creating another few hundred meg layers every time you build.  But if you run

```
FROM debian
RUN apt-get song and dance  my-system deps && clean up after myself
MKDIR /code
COPY ./code/requirements /code/requirements
RUN pip or gem thingy
COPY /code/
...
```

Now you don't have to install requirements every time.  So the bulk of your environment (system and language libraries) doesn't need to change.  You should only need the space for whatever you copy in ./code and thereafter in this case - still usually in the 0.1 gig or so magnitude.

The community tends to tout minimization of layers in an image and as far as steps with the same lifespan and dependencies  (apt-get install / cleanup ) it makes sense.  But this is actually contrary to efficiency if you can make good use of caching.  For example, if you need to change gem file, probably don't need to change all of system libraries, so no need to rebuild that image unless you *want* to update the lower layers. This also drastically increases build time if you don't have to install libffi-dev or whatever every time.

Likely the biggest thing you can do to keep final image sizes down is use multi stage builds.  Python and Ruby containers often end up pulling in complex build time dependencies that are then kept in the final image.  Removing them from the end image is also a potential security bonus, at least security overhead in terms of CVE exposure.  So look up multi stage builds if you haven't yet and spend an hour seeing if it's fairly easy to get some of the build time dependencies out of your final image.  Full disclosure:  I cannot be sure at the moment whether these build stages are automatically cleaned up.

> And if so, should I actively be clearing old builds?

Since disk space is a fundamentally limited resource, the only question is how actively, and to what extent do you want to mitigate by increasing hard disk space.

And don't forget to clean up old containers ,too.  I try to make `docker run --rm` a habit whenever possible, but still find myself pruning them after they inevitably build up.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a good way to determine the total volume of all my images? In my example it's less than 1.6GB x 3 since you mentioned it caches layers in between.

Comment: look in the directories they're stored; your docker config will know where that is

Answer (score 1):

If one build requires 1.6G then just changing a few lines is not going to change the size.

If you are not planning to use them anymore, I would suggest clearing out the old builds. Every so often I do a `docker system prune -a` which removes unused data (images, containers, volumes, etc.).

Comment: Changing one byte of a file added in a prior layer will cause later steps to be executed again and therefore the amount of space _between_ images will be different depending on which layer the file changed in.

Comment: Thank you! What logic does `docker prune` use to clear "old" items? Just checking that it's safe to blindly run in production and it's not going to clear something currently being used.

Comment: In keeping with your methodical perspective, best to get it "straight from the horse's mouth" (an idiom of which I find myself aware, though I know next to nothing about equestrianism): https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/ pretty good page, worth a solid read

Comment: I certainly recommend reading the link suggested by @DanielFarrell. I probably would recommend against do a `docker system prune -a` in production, just in case, and suggest being more selective with what you are pruning.

Answer (score -1):

Each build is a full container, not just a layer on top of an older container. In other words, if you update your image 4 times and rebuild, you have 4 full copies of you app running. Each one is going to take up approximately the same amount of space because they are very similar to one another other than the incremental changes you’ve made between each build.

In this context, I don’t think there’s any reason not to clear out the old containers. They are clearly consuming a lot of space. Presumably, you’ve updated them for a reason, so unless you are continuing to use/test the old version of your app and need to keep it for that reason, it probably makes sense to at least periodically clear them out. This is assuming you’re doing all this in a development environment (ie, your personal/work machine) and having old versions lying around dormant doesn’t pose a security risk because they aren’t actively connecting to external services. If these are running on a live server somewhere, dump the old ones as soon as they are no longer being used so that you aren’t unnecessarily exposing any extra attack surface on your production servers.

Comment: containers?  The screenshot shows images. "Container" and "Image" are not interchangeable.   "if you update your image 4 times and rebuild, you have 4 full copies of you app running"  That's inaccurate.  Rebuilding _is_ updating your image; `docker build` creates images.  This does _not_ mean you have anything running.  An image creates a container upon being `docker run` . Further, layers _can_ be shared bewtween images _and_ between running containers,  so this is inaccurate.  
i agree that cleaning up containers after use is all around good. Yay more chores :/